# Adding things to a different route with a POST Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and am trying to use $rootScope to save values that have been selected from a dynamically generated options element, so that I can render them at a different route.  The selection options are referred to by 'ng-model' in the html, and there are four distinct ng-models that I want to grab. the models are key value pairs and I want want only the keys.

I am also including my HTML as it seems like I might need to access the ng-model inside the controller?

```
    angular.module('FFTrades.tradeanalyzer', [])

    .controller('TradesController', function($scope, $rootScope, TradesDataFactory) {

        $scope.data = {};
        $scope.selectedItem1 = 0;
        $scope.selectedItem2 = 0;
        //I want to push the selected items here.
        $rootScope.data = {};

        $scope.getPlayerData = function() {
            // getting this from the services.
            TradesDataFactory.getPlayerInfo().then(function(playerInfo) {
                $scope.data.playerInfo = playerInfo;

            }).catch(function(error) {
                //console.error(error)
            })
        }


        $scope.calc = function() {
            //selectedItem1 is a number. I want its key!
            $scope.calculatedValue1 = Number($scope.selectedItem1);
            if($scope.selectedItem2){
                    $scope.calculatedValue1 = Number($scope.selectedItem1) + Number($scope.selectedItem2);

            }

        }

        $scope.calc2 = function() {
            $scope.calculatedValue2 = Number($scope.selectedItem3);
            if ($scope.selectedItem4) {

            $scope.calculatedValue2 = Number($scope.selectedItem3) + Number($scope.selectedItem4);
            };

        }
         for (var key in $scope.data.playerInfo) {
        //this is all the players. I just want the ones that have been selected.  the problem is $scope.selectedItem4 
        //for example, is a number, not a key
    };
        var selectedItems = []
        $scope.getPlayerData();

    });


<div>Your Team Receives:</div>
    <br> Player 1:
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem1" ng-change="calc()">
        <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo" ng-value="v" >{{k}}
****//{{k}} displays the name of the player only, which is what I want to push to rootScope ****
</option>
        </select>
        Player 2:
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem2" ng-change="calc()">
            <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo" ng-value="v">{{k}}</option>
        </select>
        <!-- show value here -->
        <p> Total Value: {{calculatedValue1}} </p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div>Their Team Gets:</div>
        <br> Player 1:
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem3" ng-change="calc2()">
            <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo" ng-value="v" >{{k}}</option>
        </select>Player 2:
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem4" ng-change="calc2()">
            <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo" ng-value="v">{{k}}</option>
        </select>
        <!-- show value here -->
        <p> Total Value: {{calculatedValue2}} </p>
    <br>
```

Comment: Question is far too broad and has too much code in it. Need to scale issue down to be more specific with only relevant code for that issue

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: I just updated the question per your feedback. My question is, how do I structure a post request to get the data from/submitted to TradeStream.html?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like:

> ```
> <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem1" ng-change="calc(selectedItem1)">
> ```

```
  $scope.calc = function(model) {
        //selectedItem1 is a number. I want its key!
  }
```

Comment: what does the `:` in `/api/:route/` and the `@` in `@players` mean?

Comment: custon variable you can change for any method call, please take a 5 min read in this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource you will find what you need.

Comment: I think ultimately $rootScope would be best for me. I am editing my question to ask about $rootScope